# Does The Test Blockchain Get Reset/Cleared?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, ropsten

hi i am working with solidity and blockchain and i wanted to find out about how often the ropsten-testnet gets reset.

i cant find what i'm looking for so maybe it doesn't get reset, but if it doesn't get reset, then it seems too good to be true that the ethereum testnets will provide unlimited storage and data space for free? (because you can withdraw as much as you want from things like faucet.metamask.io)

Comment: Storage is limited to gaslimit per block

Comment: ok. but i can store as many times as i want? and so can many other addresses other than my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does The Test Blockchain Get Reset/Cleared?

They can do. There's no guarantee that the public testnets will persist for the amount of time you need them.

If we're talking about the proof of work testnets, we're currently on the third iteration, the "Ropsten Revival" testnet. The original Ropsten was a victim of spam attacks and was retired before being revived. Going back further, the Morden testnet was taken down I think because it lacked replay protection. (Or something similar?)

See:

- [From Morden to Ropsten](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/)
- [Ropsten testnet is under kind of attack? What can we do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do)
- Also related: [What is the proof that Mainnet can't be reset?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/what-is-the-proof-that-mainnet-cant-be-reset)

So in the past testnets have only been reset as a consequence of attacks or upgrade requirements. That doesn't mean these will be the only reasons going forward.

> because you can withdraw as much as you want from things like faucet.metamask.io

The supply from faucets isn't (shouldn't be) limitless. Else you could accumulate enough test ether to potentially spam/attack the network.

There are some details about the tiered withdrawal limits for the Rinkeby testnet faucet, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/68snz2/bumped_rinkeby_faucet_limits_added_withdrawal/). (Rinkeby is PoA, not PoW as Ropsten is, but still gives you an idea of how faucets have to be limited.)

---

In response to one of the comments on the other answer:

> but I think if the contract you are using becomes inactive then it is deleted or you cannot access it anymore.

That shouldn't be the case. The testnet should operate in the same way as the main net. Contracts shouldn't just disappear :-)

Comment: thank you. this was the answer i was looking for. are you able to provide any sources on this for further reading?

Comment: I've added some links to the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about it, but I think if the contract you are using becomes inactive then it is deleted or you cannot access it anymore. I've had contracts that I've published and not used for a few days and come back and haven't been able to access them.

Comment: thank you for your reply. but is there some official documentation explaining this?

Comment: Maybe you are using private testnet (localhost, ...) and lost track of previous net. Public testnet should never reset unless something unusual happen (too big people vote to reset, an attack, new version).